# binance websocket @openInterest

Tags: websocket, binance

Does anybody know how to properly connect to Binance's @openInterest websocket?
There's no problem of getting data from a stream '@kline_1m', but '@openInterest' is still a problem.

I tried different paths, but none of them outputs data. Here it is:

**Connected, no response**

```
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ETH@openInterest
    wss://nbstream.binance.com/eoptions/stream?streams=ETH@openInterest
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{relevant}
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ETH@openInterest
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ETH@openInterest@221125
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ethusdt@openInterest@221125
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ethusdt@openInterest@
    wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ethusdt@openInterest
    wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=ethusdt@openInterest/bnbusdt@openInterest
```

**200, connection closed**

```
    wss://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt 
    wss://fapi.binance.com:443/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt
    wss://fapi.binance.com:443/fapi/v1/openInterest
```

**No connection at all**

```
    wss://fapi.binance.com:9443/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt 
    wss://fstream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ethusdt@openInterest
```

**Handshake status 404 Not Found**

```
    wss://stream.binancefuture.com/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt 
    wss://fstream.binance.com/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt
    wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt
    wss://fstream.binance.com/fapi/v1/openInterest
    wss://fstream.binance.com/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ethusdt
```

UPDATE: I managed to connect though HTTPS and get part of data:

```
https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/openInterest?symbol=ETHUSDT
```

The response data is cut down to these 3 elements:

```
symbol: "ETHUSDT"
openInterest: "19862007"
time: 1709767446374
```